# How to automate - download a file and save it in internet explorer browser using C# .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, internet-explorer, automation

I am able to download the file which I want to target, but the problem is IE is asking option to open or save it, instead of directly saving it to the folder.  I want the file(.xls) which I downloaded to be saved in any specific folder.

Comment: If you only have an ASP.NET without a client app or plugin installed, should be impossible, since otherwise I can just put dangerous.exe on client's machine.

Answer (score 0):

why you are not using WebClient.DownloadFile ?

Comment: I tried using SELENIUM WEB DRIVER in IE 11, but it is not working. Used this method - [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: you can configure IE for automatic downloads or open downloaded file..
please check links

[link](https://superuser.com/questions/246553/how-to-disable-file-download-popup-in-internet-explorer)

[link](https://superuser.com/questions/273372/how-to-get-ie8-to-auto-save-downloaded-files-to-a-specific-directory)

[link](https://jwcooney.com/2014/03/31/remove-internet-explorer-open-or-save-popup/)

Comment: if you use spy tool over open save dialog, its class is DirectUIHWND. google it and you will get some ways to automate this through scripts or code.
[link](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/130585-finding-the-control-vs-the-window-using-class/)
[link](https://gist.github.com/srinivasapulagam/3016355)
[link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2847/Automated-IE-SaveAs-MHTML)
hope it will give you some ideas

Answer (score 0):

@h.munawar - and what the next? WebClient.DownloadFile will download file from source to the server, not client machine!

Here is as I'm understand goal is to download file to the client's machine

Comment: I'm not UX and UI expert, but I think answer could be found here: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/14525/how-to-handle-a-download-file-in-selenium-ide

Comment: tried with this and it worked:

WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie] = cookieString(driver); 
client.DownloadFile(href, filename);